# In web applications, is SRP a secure alternative for SSL/ TLS (server certificate) ?

Tags: security, ssl, meteor

Meteor uses the [Secure Remote Password Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) (SRP) to authenticate users. The Meteor documentation does not make any further claims regarding level of security provided but I was wondering if SRP can provide security without the need for SSL/ TLS? The Wikipedia page on SRP states:

> ... an eavesdropper or man in the middle cannot obtain enough
>   information to be able to brute force guess a password without further
>   interactions with the parties for each guess ...

I admit I know very little about security but I could not find any recommendations regarding its use.

Many thanks

Comment: To add to Jerry Coffin's answer: SRP is supported by TLS specification and some TLS engines. I.e. if you don't want certificates, you can go with TLS and SRP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SRP is *only* for exchanging a password. More accurately, it's purely for giving both ends of communication assurance that they both have possession of the same shared secret, without allowing an eavesdropper or man in the middle a way to guess at the shared secret. That's all it does though: two-way authentication, so if/when (for example) I log into a server, I know the server is really the one I wanted to log into, and it knows that I'm a user with a correct password.

It does *not*, however, (even attempt to) create an encrypted connection between the parties like SSL/TLS. Although somebody listening in can't gain enough information about the password involved to log in in my place (or imitate a server for others to log into), it does *not* (by itself) encrypt further communications--unless you do more than just SRP by itself, anybody else will still be able to read all the data passing over the connection.

Comment: Yes, but it creates a shared secret that is not known by an eves dropper nor, much more importantly, a phisher.  And that secret can be used to encrypt a link.  That said, TLS is fine for encrypting a link to someone, you just do not know who you are talking to (presuming that no end user can verify a URL which is true in practice).

Answer (score 3):

I know, I'm a bit late with answer here, but just decided to add some clarification. As Jerry Coffin said, SRP is for password exchange with proof of both sides possessing some shared secret, and it doesn't provide any encryption by itself, BUT, during handshake process both sides generates the same secret key, which can be later used for encryption/decryption by some other algorithms, i.e. AES-256.
But if you decide to use this method of authentication, you should consider this:

1. During user registration it sends it's salt and verifier to server in plain text, so attacker is capable of bruteforcing or dictionary attack it offline. To prevent it you'd better use at least SHA256 hashing with safe prime N=2048 bytes or higher(In my case SHA512 and N=8192 seems to work fast enough, while being a HUGE overkill). And a strong user password of course.
2. Attacker possessing verifier and salt won't be able to authenticate on server, but he COULD pose himself as a server to client. He won't be able to get a key, or establish a MITM attack, though. In most cases it's pretty useless for attacker, but you never know...
3. If you are planning to implement this protocol in some kind of web interface, be aware that it won't protect your users against a simple phishing. Since in browser it require JavaScript to secure password before sending, bad guys could just feed user a plain html-form, sending plain text password wherever they want.  So TLS/SSL is highly recommended anyway.

So to summ up: SRP is great additional layer of security, which helps to protect users passwords, generate a session encryption keys, authenticate client to server, and protect from MITM attack,  but it's much more secure if it's inside a TLS/SSL channel.

And shall the os.urandom be with you! ;)